# Unable to import python file from different directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-module

I have the following folder hierarchy.

```
apriltag
    python
        apriltag.py
my_notebook.ipynb
```

I simply want to import [apriltag.py](https://github.com/swatbotics/apriltag/blob/master/python/apriltag.py) into my Jupyter Notebook. I tried doing it this way..

```
import sys
import os.path

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__')) + "/apriltag/python")

import apriltag
```

However, when I try to access a class from `apriltag`, like so:

```
print(apriltag.Detector)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-d1254ec9a372> in <module>()
     12 import apriltag
     13 
---> 14 print(apriltag.Detector)

AttributeError: module 'apriltag' has no attribute 'Detector'
```

Suggesting that the module was not imported correctly. I've tried creating `__init__.py` at the root of the `python` directory as well but the same thing occurred.

Comment: Does `from apriltag import Detector` work?

Comment: `dir(apriltag)` will probably tell you a lot.

Comment: @TreytenCarey `cannot import name 'Detector'`

Comment: @ScottMermelstein this is the output `['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']` not sure how to interpret it

Comment: That's an empty module.  The next thing I would check is `print(apriltag.__path__)`, and see if it's pointing to apriltag/python/apriltag.py, or just apriltag.  (Compare both the results of the dir and the __path__ to what you'd get by inspecting sys or some other thing that imported well.  `dir(sys)` and `print(sys.__path__)` would give you an idea of what to expect when it's properly loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to buzz in a little bit early.  I may have the solution to your problem.  If I don't, we can go back to figuring it out.

As you've probably seen, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) say

> The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path,

Now, you're running my_notebook.ipynb, so it's directory is the very beginning of the search path.  And you probably have an `__init__.py` file in the apriltag directory that's at the same level.  As such, it's being found as a module, and loaded.  And there are no .py files in that "module", and nothing in your `__init__.py` there, so it's loading as an empty module.

Instead, don't try modifying the sys.path directory, just make empty `__init__.py` files in both the apriltag and the python directories.

Then, you should be able to do the following:

```
from apriltag.python import apriltag
```

The apriltag that gets imported should be the one you need.  (And `dir(apriltag)` will give you much nicer results.)

Generally, I always set up all my code in directories with empty `__init__.py` and invoke them all with the `from` syntax.  It made modules a lot easier to handle.